# tbb::parallel_reduce vs tbb::parallel_deterministic_reduce

Tags: c++, reduce, tbb, deterministic

Threading Building Blocks (TBB) library provides two functions for performing reduction over a range:

- [parallel_reduce](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/1.0-rev-1/elements/oneTBB/source/algorithms/functions/parallel_reduce_func.html), and
- [parallel_deterministic_reduce](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/1.0-rev-1/elements/oneTBB/source/algorithms/functions/parallel_deterministic_reduce_func.html).

Which one of two shall be selected if I want to perform the reduction as fast as possible, but still get exactly the same answer independently on hardware concurrency and the load from other processes or threads? I am basically interested in two scenarios:

1. Computing the sum of elements in *integer*-value vector.
2. Computing the sum of elements in *floating-point*-value vector.

And a side question. On the page about `parallel_deterministic_reduce` there is one warning:

> Since `simple_partitioner` does not automatically coarsen ranges, make sure to specify an appropriate grain size

Does it mean that the call to `parallel_deterministic_reduce` with a range having no explicitly specified grain size will lead to poor performance? How grain size shall be set then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parallel_reduce` does not make any guarantees regarding the summation order. If used with floating point numbers, the result is not deterministic since summation of floating point numbers is not associative.
In contrast, `parallel_deterministic_reduce` guarantees that the summation order is always the same, regardless of the number of threads used. But note that there is still no guarantee of a specific summation order, just that the order is deterministic (for example, the result can differ compared to `std::accumulate`).

Thus:

- In case of integers, you should use `parallel_reduce` for best performance.
- For floating point numbers, you should use `parallel_deterministic_reduce` if you need deterministic behavior.

Regarding the note that `simple_partitioner` does not automatically coarsen ranges: I am not entirely sure why they mention this specifically in the documentation of `parallel_deterministic_reduce`. In **all** cases where you use `simple_partitioner`, you should think about appropriate grain sizes. Not just in case of `parallel_deterministic_reduce`. A too small grain size can lead to a large overhead. See for example [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4842-4398-5_16). In practice this especially means to **measure** the performance for typical work loads, and play with the grain size or partitioner such that performance is maximized.
I guess they just wanted to highlight the general issue again for `parallel_deterministic_reduce` because `parallel_deterministic_reduce` supports only `simple_partitioner` and `static_partitioner`, but neither `affinity_partitioner` nor `auto_partitioner` (where the latter is usually the default).